# Prove of irrationality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, irrational-numbers

how can I prove that $(1-\sqrt{2})^z $ is never rational for any integer $z$ different from $0$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $(1-\sqrt{2})(1+\sqrt{2})=-1$ so $(1-\sqrt{2})^z$ is rational if and only if
$$(1+\sqrt{2})^z=\sum_{k=0}^z\binom{z}{k}\sqrt{2}^k,$$
is rational. But this is clearly of the form $a+b\sqrt{2}$ for some positive integers $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Why go through $(1+\sqrt 2)^z$? The binomial theorem works just as well on $(1-\sqrt2)^z$ directly (yes, $b$ becomes negative, but that doesn't change the result in the slightest).

Comment: @Arthur I think in the $(1-\sqrt{2})^z$ case we will need to prove that $b \ne 0$

Comment: All terms with $\sqrt2$ raised to some odd power will have negative sign. So you get the exact same $b$ as you do for $(1+\sqrt2)^z$, only with opposite sign.

Comment: @Arthur You are absolutely right, I just found that this representation illustrates the point more clearly.